# How to get a running history diff log in subversion?

Tags: svn, diff

Is it possible to get a history of all changes to a certain file **including** the actual lines that changed?

Something like `svn log --with-diffs myfile.txt` which would output the commit messages as usual + the diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to subversion 1.7 then use svn log --diff

http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html